# Ruby bundler installing unwanted version of puppet gem

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet

I have the following script

```
PUPPET_VERSION=3.7.4
ruby='1.8.7-p374'

rvm use $ruby@$$ --create
gem install bundler
bundle install --gemfile=.gemfile
```

This has worked for several months but sadly now it has decided to stop working.

After this script rake is called to run some rspec tasks

On the centos 6.6 bamboo test runner the process fails.
On the centos 6.4 development machine it still works

On my development machine this script (+rake tasks ) works like so

```
    Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Installing rake 10.4.2
Installing CFPropertyList 2.2.8
Installing builder 3.2.2
Installing diff-lcs 1.2.5
Installing facter 2.4.1
Installing json_pure 1.8.2
Installing hiera 1.3.4
Installing metaclass 0.0.4
Installing mocha 1.1.0
Installing puppet 3.7.4
Installing puppet-lint 1.1.0
Installing puppet-syntax 1.4.1
Installing rspec-core 2.99.2
Installing rspec-expectations 2.99.2
Installing rspec-mocks 2.99.3
Installing rspec 2.99.0
Installing rspec-puppet 2.0.0
Installing puppetlabs_spec_helper 0.8.2
Installing rspec_junit_formatter 0.2.0
Using bundler 1.9.4
Bundle complete! 3 Gemfile dependencies, 20 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
manifests found
~/gitf/puppetmaster_np/local_modules/iop_4store/spec/fixtures/modules ~/gitf/puppetmaster_np/local_modules/iop_4store
~/gitf/puppetmaster_np/local_modules/iop_4store
/home/jan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/classes/iop_4store_spec.rb --no-drb -r rspec_junit_formatter --format RspecJunitFormatter -o junit.xml --deprecation-out /dev/null
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      rake (>= 0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Removing gemset 16612......
```

However on the bamboo agent node it does this

```
The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
Using rake 10.4.2
Using CFPropertyList 2.2.8
Using builder 3.2.2
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using facter 2.4.3
Using json_pure 1.8.2
Using hiera 2.0.0
Using metaclass 0.0.4
Using mocha 1.1.0
Using puppet 4.0.0
Using puppet-lint 1.1.0
Using puppet-syntax 2.0.0
Using rspec-support 3.2.2
Using rspec-core 3.2.3
Using rspec-expectations 3.2.1
Using rspec-mocks 3.2.1
Using rspec 3.2.0
Using rspec-puppet 2.0.1
Using puppetlabs_spec_helper 0.10.2
Using rspec_junit_formatter 0.2.0
Using bundler 1.9.4
Bundle complete! 3 Gemfile dependencies, 21 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
manifests found
~/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/PUP-RCTAP-JOB1/local_modules/iop_4store/spec/fixtures/modules ~/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/PUP-RCTAP-JOB1/local_modules/iop_4store
~/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/PUP-RCTAP-JOB1/local_modules/iop_4store
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby -I/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-support-3.2.2/lib:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb --no-drb -r rspec_junit_formatter --format RspecJunitFormatter -o junit.xml --deprecation-out /dev/null
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      rake (>= 0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/puppetlabs_spec_helper-0.10.2/lib/puppetlabs_spec_helper/module_spec_helper.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `environmentpath=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x000000025a4068> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core.rb:101:in `configure'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/puppetlabs_spec_helper-0.10.2/lib/puppetlabs_spec_helper/module_spec_helper.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/PUP-RCTAP-JOB1/local_modules/iop_4store/spec/spec_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/PUP-RCTAP-JOB1/local_modules/iop_4store/spec/classes/iop_4store_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby -I/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-support-3.2.2/lib:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb --no-drb -r rspec_junit_formatter --format RspecJunitFormatter -o junit.xml --deprecation-out /dev/null failed
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@27314 did not previously exist. Ignoring.
```

The tests fail and I'm sure that having a wildly different version of puppet (and other gems) is not helping.  Also, our systems aren't running puppet 4

Here is the gemfile that is being used

```
source :rubygems

puppetversion = ENV.key?('PUPPET_VERSION') ? "= #{ENV['PUPPET_VERSION']}" : ['>=
 2.7']
gem 'puppet', puppetversion
gem 'puppetlabs_spec_helper', '>= 0.1.0'
gem 'rspec_junit_formatter'
```

So my problem is that the scripts shown previously loaded the correct gems into rvm and executed the tests "as if" puppet 3.7.0.  Now they try and load puppet 4 and the tests fail.

Thanks

Comment: Is `Gemfile.lock` versioned? Sounds like your local has puppetversion locked to `3.7.4`. Anyway, `puppetversion = ENV.key?('PUPPET_VERSION') ? "= #{ENV['PUPPET_VERSION']}" : ['>=
 2.7', '< 4.0']` should solve the problem.

Comment: Do you not need to `export` PUPPET_VERSION so that it shows up in Ruby's environment? (I'm thinking of a behavioral change in shells between your OS releases.)

Comment: mudaasobwa that makes sense, thanks.  Felix good call but I don't believe it was that.  I now have a cargo cultish workaround but will wait a couple of days to see if a real answer crawls out of the woodwork.  We have puppet enterprise support but they don't support the puppet-rspec stuff

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to "make it work"  Not entirely sure why this fixed it

First, alter the gemfile to copy most of the versions of the gem dependencies from the other server where it still works

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

puppetversion = ENV.key?('PUPPET_VERSION') ? "= #{ENV['PUPPET_VERSION']}" : ['>=
 2.7', '< 4.0']
 gem 'diff-lcs',  '1.2.5'
 gem 'facter'
 gem 'hiera',  '1.3.4'
 gem 'json_pure',  '1.8.2'
 gem 'metaclass',  '0.0.4'
 gem 'mocha',  '1.1.0'
 gem 'puppet', puppetversion
 gem 'puppet-lint',  '1.1.0'
 gem 'puppet-syntax',  '1.4.1'
 gem 'puppetlabs_spec_helper',  '0.8.2'
 gem 'rake'
 gem 'rspec',  '2.99.0'
 gem 'rspec-core',  '2.99.2'
 gem 'rspec-expectations',  '2.99.2'
 gem 'rspec-mocks',  '2.99.3'
 gem 'rspec-puppet',  '2.0.0'
 gem 'rspec_junit_formatter',  '0.2.0'
```

Next, add a couple of "bundle update" and a "bundlee clean --force" to the script.

```
PUPPET_VERSION=3.7.4
ruby='1.9.3-p484'

rvm use $ruby@$$ --create
gem install bundler
ln -s .gemfile Gemfile
bundle clean --force
bundle update rspec
bundle install --gemfile=.gemfile
bundle update rspec
```

(the eagle eyed will note that I'm running a different ruby too)